# RAID in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: raid

I'v been red about how to create RAID partitions during installations but it seems to need "alternative installation CD". Unfortunately, there is no download link for alternative ubuntu 14.04. Why? Is there any other way to build RAID partitions without ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The alternate desktop image was dropped.  If you want to go that route, you can use the server install image, then install the regular desktop software on top.  Or instead, you can install the mdadm package in the regular live environment, and use the disk utility ( if you aren't comfortable with the command line ) to partition the disk and create the raid array, then run the installer and choose "something else" and point it to the raid array(s).